# How to format Date Input that only the format I want can continue

Tags: javascript, php, html

Right now I am Working on a reserving system and I got a Problem.
I never needed such a thing before.
I want the Owner to be able to lock some days with format `dd/mm/jjjj` .
And i want to prevent the owner to input his own format like `dd.mm.jj` or `dd.mm.jjjj` how is this possible pref. without date function :) ?

Dont mind my bad eng. wishes from ger.

Kind Regards
Marvin

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert one date format into another in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167916/convert-one-date-format-into-another-in-php)

Comment: Share your some code. And you lock some days when you extract days from date.

Comment: You can use https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/ and keep date field readonly

Comment: @Hemantwagh07 well that solved my problem really like I wanted it to be.
Im already using another datepicker but forgot about readonly. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try it with the date method

```
<?php
$date = "2017-03-07";
date('d.m.Y',strtotime($date));
?>
```

this snippet outputs 07.03.2017

Best regards from Germany too

Comment: Also tryed this out but the customer who uses the system should not be able to input his own format, so i used the solution Hemantwagh07 suggested with readonly and a datepicker.

Comment: Okay, but remind that javascript always can be manipulated by the user

Comment: Yes that would be the best way :)